# How to generate python code from WSDL using ZSI?

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, generated-code, zsi

I installed ZSI package.
I have wsdl file and I want to generate python code from it.
Is there a command-line tool in ZSI to generate python code from WSDL or I need to write my own class for this and call wsdl2python methods?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Create file wsdl2py with the following content:

```
#!/bin/env python
from ZSI.generate.commands import wsdl2py
wsdl2py()
```

Give this file executable permissions.

Run command:

./wsdl2py --file my_file.wsdl

This will generate two python files:

my_file_services.py

my_file_services_types.py